# Linkedin company page updates - 403

Tags: linkedin-api, spring-social-linkedin

We have a company page update feed that worked until recently. The feed is downloaded using spring social linkedin and we use the parameters consumerkey, consumersecret, **accessToken** and **accessTokenSecret**.

Without changing anything we just recently started geting the response 403 - Forbidden. The app is a couple of years old and from what i heard that the usertoken and secret was available there, but not anymore.

Is there any changes to the linkedin api this last week that made it not work? Or is it because linkedin removed the usertoken and secret from the apps?